# DoSing Apache versions

Tags: apache, denial-of-service

Can denial of service attacks affect Apache V2.4 or more? Using Slowloris.pl
Or how to DoS Apache servers V2.4 or more?

Comment: You can find out by looking at the vulnerabilities in the specific Apache version you are dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

You can DOS anything, including Apache. Its only a question of how much resources the server can allocate and how much resources you are able to request (i.e. bandwidth, connections...).  If you can request more than the server can handle you have a DOS, i.e. denied legitimate users access to the site. You don't even need attack tools because it might be sufficient to make lots of users want to visit the site, see [Slashdot effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot_effect).

Thus the question is not if DOS is possible but how easy it is. This depends on the version of the server, its setup etc. Tools like slowloris help as do tools which makes lots of request or tools which do lots of computationally intensive TLS handshakes. And depending on the site  it might be even cheaper for the attacker to DOS  the web application itself, for example with regex complexity attacks, XXE or causing expensive database queries.